# Multiple Server in one app

Tags: php, mysql, server

i have developed an enrolment system which uses 1 server. I have unused server which I'm planning to use as server also for enrolment system. How can i configure those servers so that my system can interact to the 2 servers? or if one server is busy the other server will be used?

Comment: What you can do, have single Database and two stateless servers using the database. Make sure Database is the one handle if the data being persisted correctly and not the server. Servers are to do "Here's some data, save it on the database". I only read up on this and haven't implemented it.

Comment: :) sorry i dont understand..  in my server, mysql database and my php files resides.

Comment: That rely on three server infrastructure, we use AWS nodes as individual machine. So you need either 3 physical machines or a one machine with two virtual servers and another for Database

Comment: @funfunky31  Do you have 2 different databases which resides in 2 different servers. This is what you meant?

Comment: I'm more familiar with LXD containers in cluster, so I'm not much of a expert in this field

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari nope, one database server, with two server  able to access the data at the same time. Load balancing and also works as fail over. You can have a look at Fabio Load Balancer

Comment: @Channaveer. not yet. i have a single server where php files and mysql database resides. and i want to make use of the other server.

Comment: can you please suggest sites? :) i dont know what to search because i dont know the terms or words to search

Comment: Can you please give an example of how the infrastructure your looking out for so that we can help you in better

Comment: Three-tier Client / Server Architecture.  i found this.  thats what i want to achieve. but i dont know how

Comment: @Channaveer. i dont know if this is possible. i have multiple users of enrollment system.  when they all simultaneously uses the system it will take minutes to retrieve the data. so maybe a solution is to put another server to manage the traffic.

Comment: Then try the load balance. Which will help you to achieve this.

Comment: Hello,
The easy way is to put a proxy (haproxy for example). It will handle all the requests and dispatch them on your servers.
Then you need a database, it will get the data your servers need. If you are using sessions you have to put them in the database because two requests can be dispatched between two servers.